# How to create own generator with the Flutter engine

Tags: flutter, code-generation, codegen

When you do i18n in Flutter you can define a `generate:true` flag in *pubspec.yaml* which tells the framework to create and recreate a `.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n` dir with the translations of the project on every hot restart.

Is that extensible? I want to generate `.dart_tool/flutter_gen/my_own_shit/latest_modification.dart` with, e.g. a variable `latestModification` with the date of the latest edited file in the project. Is that possible?

Note that although `package:build` provides functionality like this, up to what I know, you have to run the build through `build_runner`. The framework does this whenever a `generate:true` y read instead.